# How can I compute determinant of n order where n is a variable with mathematica or maple or maxima?

Tags: wolfram-mathematica, maxima, maple

For example, an n*n matrix

```
A_n=[2 1 1 ... 1]
    [1 2 1 ... 1]
    [...     ...]
    [1 1 1 ... 2]
```

has determinant n+1. Can I compute this result by these softwares?

Answer (score 0):

This

```
f[n_]:=Det[Table[1,{n},{n}]+IdentityMatrix[n]];
f[12]
```

returns `13` and seems to work for any modest sized matrix.

Comment: Your code can still be stripped down :) Remember that you can add scalars to matrices in Mathematica: `f[n_] := Det[1 + IdentityMatrix[n]]`
Isn't that beautiful? Nevertheless +1

Comment: can I directly get n+1?

Answer (score 0):

Since Maple may not easily provide a structure representing an abstract Vector or Matrix of indeterminate size you might try to recast the problem in terms of some known properties of determinants.

For example, using [Sylvester's determinant theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Determinant#Sylvester's_determinant_theorem) you could take utilize the nx1 Matrix V(n) having all entries being identically 1.

So det(A(n)) = det(Id(n) + V(n).transpose(V(n))) = 1 + det(transpose(V(n)).V(n)) = 1 + add(i,i=1..n) = 1 + n

Another way might be to consider a minor expansion along the nth row. When the nth row and nth column are removed from the initial Matrix denoted by A(n) then you obtain A(n-1). Removing the nth row and the jth column (j in 1..n-1) produces a Matrix with determinant (-1)^j. I do not show that here. But perhaps note that any of those minors are a single row-exchange away from a (n-1)x(n-1) Matrix with A(n-2) in the upper left and 1's elsewhere.

In consequence Q(n) the determinant of A(n) is given by Q(n)=2*Q(n-1)-(n-1) I believe. And Q(1)=2. Using Maple's `rsolve` command,

```
rsolve({Q(n)=2*Q(n-1)-(n-1), Q(1)=2}, Q(n));

               n + 1
```

Another approach might be to consider row-reduction along rows 2..n. You should be able to produce a new Matrix (having the same determinant) whose diagonal entries are: 2, (i+1)/i, i=2..n. The determinant is thus a conveniently telescoping product.

```
simplify( 2*product((i+1)/i, i=2..n) );

                n + 1
```

Of course it is easy enough to deal with such Matrices for size n taken at a specific value,

```
H:=n->1+Matrix(n,n,1):
with(LinearAlgebra):

seq(Determinant(H(i)),i=1..5);

            2, 3, 4, 5, 6

U7:=LUDecomposition(H(6),output=U);

                  [2  1  1  1  1  1]
                  [                ]
                  [   3  1  1  1  1]
                  [0  -  -  -  -  -]
                  [   2  2  2  2  2]
                  [                ]
                  [      4  1  1  1]
                  [0  0  -  -  -  -]
                  [      3  3  3  3]
                  [                ]
            U7 := [         5  1  1]
                  [0  0  0  -  -  -]
                  [         4  4  4]
                  [                ]
                  [            6  1]
                  [0  0  0  0  -  -]
                  [            5  5]
                  [                ]
                  [               7]
                  [0  0  0  0  0  -]
                  [               6]

# The product of the  main diagonalentries telescopes.
mul(U7[i,i],i=1..6);

                  7
```